# formatting a decimal as percentage to display in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, number-formatting

In MVC Razor view, a decimal field is required to be displayed as percentage **BUT** without percentage sign. For example  `2` or `2.5`

I understand it can be from model and it will be something like:

```
    [AutoMapIgnore]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F1}")]
    public virtual decimal OffPeakMarginPercent { get { return OffPeakMargin * 100; } }
```

But is not doing any effecting at all, currently it is being displayed as:

Currently it is being displayed as `3.00000` or `2.50000`.

Can you please guide.

I highly appriciate your guidance and help.

**Edit:**

If I format in view as below, it displays as `3.0`  or `2.5`

```
@row.OffPeakMarginPercent.ToString("0.0")
```

Comment: Well did you try `{0:n1}`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

change

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F1}")]
```

to

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P2}")]
```

and remove *100 from getter

as said [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx) format for percentages in decimal is `P` not `F`

Comment: I have tried this but still it displays like 3.00000. Can you pleased see my edit and guide ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in MVC 5 You can Change the index View If you want Just To show Two zeros After double Value

code Befor

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PRSPrice)
```

code After

```
 @Convert.ToDouble(item.PRSPrice.Value).ToString("0.00")
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.\d)?$", ErrorMessage = "Only one decimal point value allowed")]
[Range( 0.1,100)]
public virtual decimal OffPeakMarginPercent { get { return OffPeakMargin * 100; } }
```

Comment: Thanks @Carlos Landeras, I can't use regular expression for some reason. Moreover it is a calculatex field. Can you please guide why formatting is not working form Model ? Please see my edit as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try using this: {0:000.0}